# Where is my new category site?

Tags: magento-1.8

I created a new category in the backend called "Zubehör".

[image]

*Side question:* ↑ Why is `Zubehör` grayed out? ↑

I have set the url key to **zubehoer**.

But if I navigate to `www.mysite.com/produkte/beleuchtung/zubehoer` then the site does not load, I get redirected to the search instead. I also tried `www.mysite.com/produkte/beleuchtung/zubehoer.html`

- Cache is deactivated.
- I reindexed everything.
- The category is active.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: The category is grayed out means this category is not active. Can you make sure that it is active?

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment, It is active though. I tripple checked it.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot after click on the category in admin?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, added.

Comment: Can you create another category there and check if that is working?

Comment: I noticed that the url key changed back to `zubehor` for unknown reasons. This was it first value and I later changed it to `zubehoer`, but it self changed back again. It is not grayed out anymore, but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

www.mysite.com/catalog/category/view/id/153

or

www.mysite.com/produkte/beleuchtung/zubehor.html
www.mysite.com/produkte/beleuchtung/zubehor

Comment: All but `/produkte/beleuchtung/zubehor` worked! So it was a magento error. Because zubehor was how I called it first, then I renamed it to zubehoer and it stopped working.